# Cross Origin issue while rendering a content from AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have setup a bucket in AWS s3 which has video files, lots of images and js and and a main index.html file which includes all the assets. I have also enabled CloudFront and it is pointing to the s3 bucket. In my rails application i have an iframe which i point it to a cloudfront-signedurl like this

```
<iframe src="https://abcde.cloudfront.net/index.html?Expires=1418801390&Signature=Qt0Y0HT5goit&Key-Pair_id=mykeypairid"></iframe>
```

but it gives me error
 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://abcde.cloudfront.net" from accessing a frame with origin "https://example.mydomain.co". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. Notice that these are different domains, how to solve this cross origin issue so that i can load the content from a different domain onto my application?
I have also added CORS configuration on AWS to allow content from all origins, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the protocol, let the browser decide.

Remove `https`:

```
src='//abcde.cloudfront.net.....'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also add crossorigin tag before src tag:

```
<iframe crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://abcde.cloudfront.net/ind...></iframe>
```

And be sure that your AWS S3 CORS Configuration looks similar to that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

consider about remove `https:`, it worked for me